# Sortable div table

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, html-table

I'm trying to create a table using divs and I want them to be sortable (alphabetically).
Here's a snippet of two rows:

```html
<div grid-row="" grid-pad="1.5" grid-gutter="3" grid-responsive="">
  <div grid-col="1" grid-pad="1.5">*image*</div>
  <div grid-col="4" grid-pad="1.5">A-title</div>
  <div grid-col="4" grid-pad="1.5">B-author</div>
  <div grid-col="3" grid-pad="1.5">C-tag</div>
</div>
<div grid-row="" grid-pad="1.5" grid-gutter="3" grid-responsive="">
  <div grid-col="1" grid-pad="1.5">*image*</div>
  <div grid-col="4" grid-pad="1.5">D-title</div>
  <div grid-col="4" grid-pad="1.5">E-author</div>
  <div grid-col="3" grid-pad="1.5">F-tag</div>
</div>
```

Using divs makes the table responsive and neatly integrated with the Cargo site - I tried out using `<td>` elements, but I did not get the responsive result i wished for.

Is there a way to code this using these kind of divs? The most important cell to have sortable is the ones with the "title" in them. Should there be something telling which columns to be sorted too?

The site is running on the Cargo Collective platform using jQuery 2.1.3.

Comment: `Im trying to do a table using divs` Why? There's nothing wrong in using a `table` element for actual tabular data. You state you had issues when trying to use `td` elments - I'd suggest giving details of that problem instead of this less than ideal X/Y solution using `div` elements.

Comment: Yes, I didn't find a way to make the table coded with 'td' elements responsive the way I wished (edited the question now clarifying this). Using Cargo, I can very easily create a responsive table using a div, however have not found a way to make them sortable.

Comment: Use this https://datatables.net/

Comment: @Grumpy It's perfectly fine to not use blunted packages like the one you suggest and implement stuff on your own instead. Actually that is highly perferrable imo.